# How to add new fields to an existing model coming from nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I have a nuget package in my project, and I am using one model from that package. Below

```
public class InOrderItemModel
{
    public InOrderItemModel();
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

In the above class I need to add few more properties so that I can populate and use it. I have to add below

```
public string OfferCode { get; set; }
public int ItemId { get; set; }
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

I don't want to create a new class. Don't want to disturb existing value assignments and all. I just want to get the required properties so that I can add data and use it when required How can I do that ?

Comment: Creating a new class inheriting from `InOrderItemModel` is not a suitable solution, correct?

Comment: @Marco - There is different /many levels. Models having lists of class properties in it. I have given a simplified example. Not sure about inheritance. Will try to do that too.

Comment: Maybe you can get it working with extension methods (but not properties). Save the data in a static dictionary with the object as key (maybe stringified). The only thing is to clean up the key when the object gets destroyed.

Comment: @Marco - I don't want to create a new class and don't to disturb existing value assignments and all. I just want to get the required properties so that I can add data and use it when required.

Comment: You could create a PR on the repo where to model exists and mark the class as partial, from there on you can create a class with the same name and namespance and add the properties over there (in essence not really a new class)

Comment: @Klamsi- Can you please write in more detail in answer. I will try that